# 1 multiple and/or in an expression 3

Tags: python, arrays

I have a table with s limited  number of nodes in it . it has 2 dimonsions  so I call it i and j: `0≤ i≤ 5` and `0≤ j≤ 8`.

Every node in this coordinate has a `y(ij)` and `u(ij)` we have `y (i=0,1 , 2 , 3 , 4 ,5   j= 0 )=0.4`
And `u (i=0,1 , 2 , 3 , 4 ,5   j=0)= 1.82` and `u(i=0 j=1,2,… 80)=5, y(i=0 j=1,2,… 80)=6, u(i=5 j=1,2,… 80)=8` and `y(i=5 j=1,2,… 80)=9`

How to write this in python?

```
Y(i+1,j+1)=y(ij) +(1/8)**( u(ij)** (y(i-1,j)-y(i+1,j)) +y(ij)** (u(i-1,j)-u(i+1,j))  )
```

for more understanding take a look at !http://tinypic.com/view.php?pic=2vw6zb8&s=5

for each green nod you will use of 3 nods under your nod .

Comment: I'm afraid your question is unintelligible. For example, where do m, r and l come in? Why does j go up to 80? Reformat at least the last lines using e.g. code blocks to make things readable.

Comment: I agree... Also the title is not about what you want to achieve i think (but my English skills are rusty so i may be wrong) from what i understood you want to declare and use arrays so look to my answer and convert it to phyton if there is not better one yet

Answer (score 0):

**Wow that is really messy.**

- Please rewrite the data in 2 matrices form
- so we actually can see what you want to do
- and then perhaps also will you.

I am no Python user but in all programming languages i used arrays are declared by [] not ()
for example 2x4 2D array of doubles in C/C++:

```
double a[2][4]=
    {
    {0.0,1.0,2.0,3.0},
    {1.0,1.1,1.2,1.3},
    }; 
double **pa=a;  // pointer to array

a[1][3]=1.0;    // direct access
pa[1][3]=2.0;   // access via pointer

//equivalent dynamic arrays creation (but have not defined values in it so it have to be initiated...
double **pb=NULL;
pb=new double*[2];
pb[0]=new double[4];
pb[1]=new double[4];

pb[0][0]=2.0;   // write
pb[0][1]=pb[0][0];  // copy

//equivalent dynamic arrays release
delete pb[0];   // for class arrays use delete[] pb[0];
delete pb[1];   // for class arrays use delete[] pb[1];
delete pb;
```